# How to pass highchart series to highchart title?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a `Pie Chart`, using `Highcharts`. I have a `title` and I need to inject the name of data series inside the title. So it's like this:

```
title: {
    text: 'Data name: {name}',
    align: 'center',
    useHTML: true,
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: -70
},

series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Some name to be injected inside the title',
    innerSize: '70%',
    data: []
}]
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by identifying or retrieving the series name first, and assigning it to a variable to be used within the chart configuration options.

Whatever method you're using to retrieve or process the data for the series object of the chart should be able to provide you the name to use independently.

Like:

```
//process data...
var seriesData = [['Group A', 1598],['Group B', 872],['Group C', 321]];
var seriesName = 'Chart Series Name';

$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart       : { type : 'pie' },
        title       : { text : seriesName },
        subtitle    : { text : null },
        tooltip     : {  },
        plotOptions : {  },
        series      : [{
            name : seriesName,
            data : seriesData
        }]
    }); 
})
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/64/

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. I suggest to use the  load event of highcharts:

```
chart: {
        /* some other code */
        events: {
            load: function () {
                //collect information
                var title_old = this.title.textStr,
                    title_new,
                    substitute= this.series[0].name,
                    needle    = '{name}';
                //replaceing 'needle' with 'substitute'
                title_new = title_old.replace(needle,substitute);
                //set title
                this.setTitle({ text: title_new});
            }
        }
    }
```

Hints:

- works only if you have one series (see in code: *series[0]*)
- tested with Highcharts JS v4.1.8 (2015-08-20)
- for information about String.prototype.replace() have a look here [1]

[1] : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: You can inject, while chart invocation you may pass name as parameters and use that name in chart config

Comment: I understood the question differently. If you do know the series-name a solution like given by jlbriggs is suitable. But if you use Ajax and do not know the series name beforehand you might use my solution given above. http://jsfiddle.net/84ek687h/6/

Comment: Luxx - my point is that you don't have to "know" it ahead of time. If you're returning ajax data containing the series name, you can pull it out and send it to the chart as the title before building the chart (or update it if you will be dynamically changing the chart). Either way, by separating the chart config and the data processing, you have plenty of flexibility to do this dynamically.